# Where/how are uploaded images stored in Cognito Forms?

Tags: cognito-forms

I created a form in Cognito Forms and tested it out with some fake info. I uploaded some images also. I am able to view/download the results in Excel. But, how & where are the uploaded images stored?

Answer (score 1):

Thanks for your question! I’m a developer for Cognito Forms.

Any attachments uploaded with form entries are stored on our cloud servers and cannot be mass exported with the rest of the form entry data. However, you can download individual attachments by going to the “Entries” page and clicking the file within the entry.

We are working on the option to mass export our form attachments, and you can track the progress of this and other upcoming features on our [Idea Board](https://trello.com/c/RBSfDsPl).

Please let us know if there is anything else we can help you with.

Answer (score 1):

OK, I was able to find it!  It does not appear in the expanded list, instead once you click a result in the expanded list, it will show your form and you can select the image in the form, and then save that image to your computer.  Thanks.